# Schedule a task to run at variable time interval

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java, Basically, I have to start a thread and run it at a default time interval say 100 seconds(comes from a variable `cooldown`). This cooldown can be updated any number of times. Suppose cooldown changes to 10 seconds, now the thread should run at intervals of 10 secs. What and how should I use to implement this? I looked into some options like `ScheduledExecutorService` but it takes a time interval which is not fixed in my case. A small example would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, seriously, care to explain the downvote? Like I mentioned, I am a total newbie to Java and would need some direction. Does that mean SO is only for experts?

Comment: Does the cooldown update need to take effect immediately, or after the next run?

Answer (score 2):

Encapsule the logic in a class and have a method that sets the interval. When the method is invoked you cancel the current scheduled task and starts a new one. It can look something like this:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService executorService = ...
private ScheduledFuture<T> future = null;

public void setCoolDown(int cooldownSec) {
    scheduleCoolDown(cooldownSec);
}

private synchronized void scheduleCoolDown(int interval) {
   if (future != null || !future.isDone()) {
        future.cancel();
   }
   future = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(theRunnable, interval, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The `synchronized` is there to make sure that only one thread can reschedule at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it with a `TimerTask`:

```
private volatile int cooldown = 100;
private Timer timer = new Timer();

private class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do work
        timer.schedule(new MyTask(), cooldown * 1000);
    }
}

private void startSchedule() {
    new MyTask().run();
}

public void setCooldown(int cooldown) {
    this.cooldown = cooldown;
}
```